# How to update RPD file in OBIEE analytics

Tags: oracle, business-intelligence

I'm new to OBIEE and looking for a way to update my repository file (RPD) i.e. I initially had an RPD configured and now have made some changes to some view in the oracle database (added on column). Now what can I do the get my RPD file updated with this change so that I can see this change (I need to work on the RPD file through administration tool).
Thanks.

Comment: Just a thought, is it possible through administration tool?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is 
1. modify the RPD
2. Stop the BI Server opmnctl stopproc ias-component=coreapplication_obis1
3. Copy the modified RPD over to  .../bifoundation/OracleBIServerComponent/coreapplication_obis1/repository. 
4.Start the BI Server opmnctl startproc ias-component=coreapplication_obis1

That's it, you are done!

You can move the RPD between Windows and Linux without a problem, as long as it is the same OBIEE version, patches etc. If that is not the case then you have to run the RPD through an upgrade process documented on OTN.

hth,